# After installing a new port, the version of a software is still old

Tags: freebsd

After installing "erlang-runtime20" from port without an exception, the version is still 19:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3.5.1] [source] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V8.3.5.1  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

even after a reboot.

```
$ uname -a
FreeBSD comp123 11.1-RELEASE FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE #0 r321309: Fri Jul 21 02:08:28 UTC 2017     root@releng2.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

update:

```
 $ pkg info erlang\*
 erlang-19.3.6.1,4
 erlang-runtime20-20.0.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the pkg's message?

> ## Message from erlang-runtime20-20.0:
>
> To use this runtime port for development or testing, just prepend its
>   binary path ("/usr/local/lib/erlang20/bin") to your PATH variable.
>
> ===========================================================================

I think you have erlang-runtime19 too and your `PATH` points to `/usr/local/lib/erlang19/bin` (you can check it with `which erl`).

So you should update your `PATH` or you can run it with full path (or maybe create an alias). And of course you can delete the `erlang-runtime19`.

Comment: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 /usr/local/bin/erl -> ../lib/erlang/bin/erl` -- no erlang19

Comment: also pkg remove erlang-runtime19 ---> `No packages matched for pattern 'erlang-runtime19'`

Comment: I think you've `erlang` installed: check `pkg info erlang\*`. If you update your `PATH` will fine. The install `erlang` version is 19!

Comment: updated my question. why "erlang" and "runtime"?

Comment: You have `erlang19` installed so `pkg remove erlang-runtime19` won't find anything. It looks like erlang20 does not install to `PATH` so you have to actually run `/usr/local/lib/erlang20/bin/erl` as mentioned in the message above. This correctly reports `Erlang/OTP 20` on my machine after installing the port. `/usr/local/bin/erl` is your old v19 and will probably disappear if you `pkg remove erlang19`

Comment: ok. there're several places where I can append something so that it'll appear in PATH, which one should I use for `/usr/local/lib/erlang20/bin`?

Comment: I don't know which shell do you use. I think the `~/.login` is a good solution: `PATH=/usr/local/lib/erlang20/bin:${PATH}`

Comment: why not ln -s?.

Comment: I don't like pollute `/usr/local` :) Another reason: if you remove `erlang-runtime20` package the link still remain (and will be a broken link). And maybe if you want install `erlang` package (which owns `/usr/local/bin/erl`) you can't. Maybe you can create a link to your `~/bin` so the `/usr/local` will be clean ;)